# Failed to install [ conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader ]

Tags: python, powershell, anaconda, pandas-datareader

I tried to install the pandas-datareader package into Anaconda but it does not work.

In Win 7 Powershell the output is:

```
Fetching package metadata ...
CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64/repodata.json>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
```

How can I fix this and instal the pandas-datareader package?

Comment: Did you try again?

Comment: yes, many times...

Comment: What is the command you're using? Do other applications have internet access? Have you tried from the anaconda prompt?

Comment: i am using the command suggested in the anaconda cloud package installation i.e.
conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader
in win powershell
but does not work

also 
conda install pandas-datareader 

does not work

Comment: Do other applications have internet access? Did you try from the Anaconda prompt?

Comment: yes I have an internet connection
I also tried to run the command from the Anaconda prompt with no success